# Duvida: Não entendi o porque da continuação

Tags: c

Faça um programa que receba a idade, o peso, a altura, a cor dos olhos (A - Azul, P -Preto, V - Verde e C - Castanho) e a cor dos cabelos (P - Preto, C - Castanho, L - Louro e R - Ruivo) de 20 pessoas e que calcule e mostre: * a quantidade de pessoas com idade superior a 50 anos e peso inferior a 60 quilos; * a média das idades das pessoas com altura inferior a 1,50; * a percentagem de pessoas com olhos azuis entre todas as pessoas analisadas; * a quantidade de pessoas ruivas e que não possuem olhos azuis.

O programa pede a idade, o peso, a altura, mas depois ele pula e não mostra mais nada. O que há de errado?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
int idade,qtd50e60=0,qtd_altura150=0,qtd_olhoazul=0,qtd_cruivas=0,qtd_cpreto=0,qtd_ccastanho=0,qtd_clouro=0,qtd_semazul=0,somaid150=0,i,qtd_olhopreto=0,qtd_olhoverde=0,qtd_olhocastanho=0,qtd_ruivas_naoazuis=0;
float peso, altura, mediaid150,percentolhoazul;
char cor_olho,cor_cabelo;
for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
{
printf("\n Digite a idade:");
scanf("%d",&idade);
printf("\n Digite o peso:");
scanf("%f\n",&peso);
printf("\n Digite a altura:");
scanf("%f",&altura);
printf("\n Informe a cor dos olhos:");
scanf("%c",&cor_olho);
printf("\n Informe a cor dos cabelos:");
scanf("%c",&cor_cabelo);
if(cor_olho=='A' || cor_olho=='P' || cor_olho=='V' || cor_olho=='C')
{
qtd_olhoazul++;
qtd_olhopreto++;
qtd_olhoverde++;
qtd_olhocastanho++;
}
if(cor_cabelo=='P' || cor_cabelo=='C' || cor_cabelo=='L' || cor_cabelo=='R')
{
qtd_cpreto++;
qtd_ccastanho++;
qtd_clouro++;
qtd_cruivas++;
}
if(idade>50 && peso<60)
{
qtd50e60++;
}
if(altura<150)
{
somaid150+=idade;
mediaid150=somaid150/qtd_altura150;
}
}
percentolhoazul=qtd_olhoazul*100/10;
printf("A quantidade de pessoas com idade superior a 50 anos e peso inferior a 60 quilos:%d\n",qtd50e60);
printf("A media das idades das pessoas com altura inferior a 1,50:%f\n",mediaid150);
printf("A percentagem de pessoas com olhos azuis entre todas as pessoas analisadas:%f\n",percentolhoazul);
printf("A quantidade de pessoas ruivas e que nao possuem olhos azuis:%d\n",qtd_ruivas_naoazuis++);
system("pause");


  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O programa tem vários erros, inclusive de lógica, vou me ater só aos mais óbvios, não vou corrigir a lógica.

Primeiro, a entrada de dados:

```
printf("\n Digite a idade:");  scanf("%d", &idade);
printf("\n Digite o peso:");   scanf("%f", &peso);
printf("\n Digite a altura:"); scanf("%f", &altura);
printf("\n Informe a cor dos olhos:"); scanf(" %c", &cor_olho);
printf("\n Informe a cor dos cabelos:"); scanf(" %c", &cor_cabelo);
```

A entrada de dados `scanf("%f\n",&peso);` tinha um '\n' a mais.
A entrada de dados das cores precisa ser assim `scanf(" %c", &cor_olho);` com um espaço antes do "%c" para consumir o '\n' da entrada anterior.

Esta lógica está errada:

```
if (cor_cabelo == 'P' || cor_cabelo == 'C' || cor_cabelo == 'L' || cor_cabelo == 'R')
{
   qtd_cpreto++;
   qtd_ccastanho++;
   qtd_clouro++;
   qtd_cruivas++;
}
```

porque ao ler **uma** cor você está contabilizando para **todas** as cores.

Esta lógica vai abortar o programa:

```
if (altura < 150)
{
   somaid150 += idade;
   mediaid150 = somaid150 / qtd_altura150;
}
```

porque `qtd_altura150` começa com zero e nunca é incrementada, por isso a divisão por zero vai abortar o programa.

Answer (score 0):

Como apresentou José X. existem não só erros na entrada de dados, como também na lógica do programa. Pode ver um exemplo desse mesmo programa no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/Nl9TZd)